# How to set field suffix as alias in Grafana with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, alias, grafana

I have graphs defined from Elasticsearch source with long field names such as private_data.systemMetrics.systemData.cpu.usage_user. I would like to set alias for the cpu usage fields that will display only the field name suffixes, in above example, usage_user.
Using Grafana v4.5.2

[image: CPU Usage graph with alias set to {{field}}:{{metric}}]

I found a way to display a short alias but it is costly. I split the query with multiple fields into a list of queries, each on a single field with explicit alias.

Is there a better way to do it?

[image: CPU Usage graph with multiple queries and explicit alias]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Please refer to [ask] to learn how to ask good questions

Comment: The 2 alternative graph definitions can be viewed from the links above